# Using i18n without culture subpath in NextJs 13

Tags: next.js, internationalization, next.js13

A key feature before I can fully move to nextJs is the translations. Currently the culture is chosen by the user at the settings page, then saved on the user settings. During initial loading I retrive the user and it's setting where the culutre is.

I thought that translation in nextjs would be the least of my problem moving my application.
But after a lot of reasearch I can't find a solution that do not utilze nextJs [Internationalization routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization).

There are solutions that disguise the url culture path. But it's seems like really clunky and unnecessary solution in my case.

I will use a state manager like Zustand or Jotai to manage the user and it's settings. And when user changes the culture I will try to use server actions and revalidate the path to update language on the page. In otherwords I will always have access to correct culture in both Client and Server.

After this wall of text, my question is... do anyone know if there is a package out there that dont depend on the culture from the url? That only translates.

Is there a good approach to this, because there will ofc be an issue to keep the RSC and Client components at sync.

These are libraries I have been looking in to:

https://github.com/aralroca/next-translate

https://www.i18next.com/

https://next-international.vercel.app/

https://github.com/i18nexus/next-i18n-router

https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/